# Let $R=\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]{3}]$. Show that for any $r\in R$ there is a polynomial $f\in\mathbb Z[x]$ such that $f(r)=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $R=\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]{3}]=\{a+b\sqrt[3]{3}+c\sqrt[3]{9}\mid a,b,c\in\mathbb Q\}$. Show that for any $r\in R$ there is a polynomial $f(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$ such that $f(r)=0$.

I took an example for $r=\sqrt{2}\in Q(\sqrt(2))$ and found polynomial $f(x)=(x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2})=x^2-2 \in Z[x]$ so that $f(\sqrt{2})=0$.

Similarly, I tried solving the original problem as follows: if $r=a+b\sqrt[3]{3}+c\sqrt[3]{9}$ where any $r\in R$ then $f(x)=(x-r)(x-s)(x-t)$ for some $s,t\in R$, where $s=\{a_1+b_1\sqrt[3]{3}+c_1\sqrt[3]{9}\}$ and $t=\{a_2+b_2\sqrt[3]{3}+c_2\sqrt[3]{9}\}$ would give a cubic polynomial $f(x)\in Z[x]$. But when you multiply all the factors, you still get $\sqrt[3]{3}$ and $\sqrt[3]{9}$ terms in the $f(x)\in Z[x]$ polynomial. Please let me know how to approach it.

Comment: Adapt https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2305565/589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $r-a=\sqrt[3]3(b+c\sqrt[3]3)$. Then $$(r-a)^3=3(b^3+3c^3)+9bc\sqrt[3]3(b+c\sqrt[3]3)\implies(r-a)^3=3(b^3+3c^3)+9bc(r-a).$$

Now I leave you the pleasure to find $f\in\mathbb Z[x]$ such that $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Great answer! Is there general technique for solving these kind of questions? I have seen solutions on this forum for finding polynomials for $\sqrt{2}$ over $Q$, $\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4}$ over $Q$. And each technique is unique. How about technique for finding polynomials for $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[5]{5}$ over $Q$.

Comment: Also, in these kind of problems when we get a polynomial in $r$ which we convert to a polynomial in $x$, we also have to show that the polynomial is irreducible right?

Comment: If there is such a technique, then I am not aware of it. But in your example the polynomial has certainly the degree $2\cdot 3\cdot 5=30$, and once you find it there is no need to show that it is irreducible. Same in the original post: the degree of the extension $\mathbb Q(r)$ over $\mathbb Q$ is three, unless $r\in\mathbb Q$, so the degree three polynomial that has $r$ as a root is necessarily irreducible.

Comment: Thanks user26857. Now I am trying to find polynomial for $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[5]{5}$ over $Q$.

Answer (score 3):

$R/\mathbb Q$ is a finite extension of fields, so it is algebraic. Explicitly, let $r\in R$. Consider
$$1,r,r^2,r^3.$$
Since $R$ is a $3$-dimensional $\mathbb Q$-vector space, these elements are linearly dependent over $\mathbb Q$. Thus, we get a linear relation
$\sum_{i=0}^3 a_i r^i=0$, where $a_i\in \mathbb Q$. This means $r$ is a root of $\sum_{i=0}^3 a_i x^i$. Multiply this by the denominators of the $a_i$ gives the desired polynomial.

Comment: I don't follow. What would be the polynomial which has root r?

Comment: This answer only shows that there is a dependency relation between the powers of $r$, but how to find it in concrete examples is still a mystery. (-1)